# How to delete a specific row of label widgets in tkinter app

Tags: tkinter, osx-lion, python-3.4

I'm having trouble finding a way to delete a row of widgets in my shares app. I'm currently experimenting with the `grid_forget` method; however this is only deleting the very last instance of the object. My aim is to be able to enter the code relating to the row which I want to delete, which will then find the code in the list of labels and delete that entire row, after which the rows will automatically adjust and move up to fill any white space. To be honest I'm not sure if this even achievable with tkinter and python, but I'm only a beginner so don't really know. The deletion code looks something like this:

```
def delete(self, event = None):
    if self.code_entry_delete.get() in self.code_list:
        self.label1.grid_forget()
        self.label2.grid_forget()
        …
        self.label10.grid_forget()
```

The problem I'm having is that `self.label1…label10` are repeated over multiple rows, so forgetting `self.label1` will only forget the most recent entry. This means I need to find a way of forgetting `self.label1` to `self.label10` at row x, where x is equal to the row number I want to remove/forget.

Full code for my incomplete but working program below. If anyone copies and pastes the code for testing, Australia uses 3 letter codes for companies on our share market, ie. STO, NAB, CBA. etc…

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4

from tkinter import *
import ystockquote
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Shares(Frame):

def __init__(self, master):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)

    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.frame = Frame(master, bg = "#ededed")
    self.frame.grid(row = 9, column = 0)
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame, bg = "#ffffff")
    self.data_frame = Frame(self.canvas, bg = "#ffffff")
    self.vscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.frame, orient = "vertical", command = self.canvas.yview)
    self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = self.vscrollbar.set)
    self.vscrollbar.grid(row = 9, column = 11, sticky = NS)
    self.canvas.config(width = 1210, height = 200)
    self.canvas.grid(row = 9, column = 0, columnspan = 11, sticky = E)
    self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window = self.data_frame, anchor = "nw", tags = "self.frame")
    self.data_frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfig)

    self.data_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize = 352)
    self.data_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1,  minsize = 96)
    self.data_frame.grid_columnconfigure(2,  minsize = 96)
    self.data_frame.grid_columnconfigure(3,  minsize = 96)
    self.data_frame.grid_columnconfigure(4,  minsize = 96)
    self.data_frame.grid_columnconfigure(5,  minsize = 96)
    self.data_frame.grid_columnconfigure(6,  minsize = 96)
    self.data_frame.grid_columnconfigure(7,  minsize = 96)
    self.data_frame.grid_columnconfigure(8,  minsize = 96)
    self.data_frame.grid_columnconfigure(9,  minsize = 96)

    master.bind("<Return>", self.company_details)

    Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", font = "Helvetica 20", text = "Enter ASX Code").grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", font = "Helvetica 20", text = "Current Price").grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady = 5)

    self.entryVar = StringVar()
    Entry(self.frame, width = 12, font = "Helvetica 20", textvariable = self.entryVar).grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)

    self.companyVar = StringVar()
    Label(self.frame, font = "Helvetica 20", textvariable = self.companyVar).grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady = 5)

    self.priceVar = DoubleVar()
    Label(self.frame, font = "Helvetica 20", textvariable = self.priceVar).grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.priceVar.set("")

    Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", font = "Helvetica 20", text = "Current Action").grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady = 5)

    Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", font = "Helvetica 20", text = "Current Holdings").grid(row = 7, column = 0, pady = 5)

    Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", width = 10, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "Name").grid(row = 8, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", width = 10, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "Code").grid(row = 8, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)
    Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", width = 10, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "Buy Date").grid(row = 8, column = 3, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", width = 10, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "Quantity").grid(row = 8, column = 4, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", width = 10, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "Paid").grid(row = 8, column = 5, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", width = 10, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "Brokerage").grid(row = 8, column = 6, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", width = 10, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "Total").grid(row = 8, column = 7, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", width = 10, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "Current").grid(row = 8, column = 8, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", width = 10, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "Total").grid(row = 8, column = 9,padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", width = 10, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "Loss/Gain").grid(row = 8, column = 10, padx = 5, pady = 5)

    Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", text = "Amount").grid(row = 16, column = 10, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)
    Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", text = "Amount").grid(row = 16, column = 9, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)
    Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", text = "Amount").grid(row = 16, column = 8, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)

    Button(self.frame, width = 11, text = "New Record", command = self.new_record).grid(row = 16, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)
    #Button(self.frame, width = 11, text = "Modify Record", command = self.new_record).grid(row = 16, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Button(self.frame, width = 11, text = "Delete Record", command = self.delete_record).grid(row = 16, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)

    self.rows = 0

    self.code_list = []

def validate_code(self):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("https://au.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" + (self.code_entry.get() + ".AX")).read(), "html.parser")
    element = soup.find("div", ("class", "title"))
    name = element.find("h2")
    self.name_entry.set(name.text[:-9])

def new_record(self):
    top = self.top = Toplevel()

    top.bind("<Return>", self.add)

    Label(top, text = "Code: ").grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = E, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(top, text = "Name: ").grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = E, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(top, text = "Buy Date: ").grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = E, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(top, text = "Quantity: ").grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = E, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(top, text = "Paid: ").grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = E, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Label(top, text = "Brokerage: ").grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = E, padx = 5, pady = 5)

    self.name_main = StringVar()
    self.label1 = Label(self.data_frame, textvariable = self.name_main)
    self.label1.grid(row = self.rows, column = 0, sticky = W)
    self.name_main.set("")

    self.name_entry = StringVar()
    Entry(top, textvariable = self.name_entry).grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.name_entry.set("")

    self.code_main = StringVar()
    self.label2 = Label(self.data_frame, textvariable = self.code_main)
    self.label2.grid(row = self.rows, column = 1, sticky = EW)
    self.code_main.set("")

    self.code_entry = StringVar()
    Entry(top, textvariable = self.code_entry, validatecommand = self.validate_code).grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.code_entry.set("")

    self.date_main = StringVar()
    self.label3 = Label(self.data_frame, textvariable = self.date_main)
    self.label3.grid(row = self.rows, column = 2, sticky = EW)
    self.date_main.set("")

    self.date_entry = StringVar()
    Entry(top, textvariable = self.date_entry).grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.date_entry.set("")

    self.quantity_main = IntVar()
    self.label4 = Label(self.data_frame, textvariable = self.quantity_main)
    self.label4.grid(row = self.rows, column = 3, sticky = E)
    self.quantity_main.set("")

    self.quantity_entry = IntVar()
    Entry(top, textvariable = self.quantity_entry).grid(row = 4, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.quantity_entry.set("")

    self.paid_main = DoubleVar()
    self.label5 = Label(self.data_frame, textvariable = self.paid_main)
    self.label5.grid(row = self.rows, column = 4, sticky = E)
    self.paid_main.set("")

    self.paid_entry = DoubleVar()
    Entry(top, textvariable = self.paid_entry).grid(row = 5, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.paid_entry.set("")

    self.brokerage_main = DoubleVar()
    self.label6 = Label(self.data_frame, textvariable = self.brokerage_main)
    self.label6.grid(row = self.rows, column = 5, sticky = E)
    self.brokerage_main.set("")

    self.brokerage_entry = DoubleVar()
    Entry(top, textvariable = self.brokerage_entry).grid(row = 6, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.brokerage_entry.set(29.95)

    self.total_main = DoubleVar()
    self.label7 = Label(self.data_frame, textvariable = self.total_main)
    self.label7.grid(row = self.rows, column = 6, sticky = E)
    self.total_main.set("")

    self.current_main = DoubleVar()
    self.label8 = Label(self.data_frame, textvariable = self.current_main)
    self.label8.grid(row = self.rows, column = 7, sticky = E)
    self.current_main.set("")

    self.total_two_main = DoubleVar()
    self.label9 = Label(self.data_frame, textvariable = self.total_two_main)
    self.label9.grid(row = self.rows, column = 8, sticky = E)
    self.total_two_main.set("")

    self.loss_gain_main = DoubleVar()
    self.label10 = Label(self.data_frame, textvariable = self.loss_gain_main)
    self.label10.grid(row = self.rows, column = 9, sticky = E)
    self.loss_gain_main.set("")

    Button(top, text = "Validate code", command = self.validate_code).grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)

    Button(top, text = "Add", command = self.add).grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady = 5)

    Button(top, text = "Cancel", command = self.cancel).grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = E, padx = 5, pady = 5)

def add(self, event = None):
    self.rows += 1
    self.code_list.append(self.code_entry.get())
    code = str.upper(self.code_entry.get())
    self.code_main.set(code)
    self.name_main.set(self.name_entry.get())
    self.date_main.set(self.date_entry.get())
    self.quantity_main.set(self.quantity_entry.get())
    paid = self.paid_entry.get()
    self.paid_main.set("$%.2f" % paid)
    brokerage = self.brokerage_entry.get()
    self.brokerage_main.set("$%.2f" % brokerage)
    total = self.quantity_entry.get() * self.paid_entry.get() + self.brokerage_entry.get()
    self.total_main.set("$%.2f" % total)
    self.current_main.set("$" + str(ystockquote.get_price(self.code_entry.get() + ".AX")))
    curent_main = float(ystockquote.get_price(self.code_entry.get() + ".AX"))
    total_two = curent_main * self.quantity_entry.get()
    self.total_two_main.set("$%.2f" % total_two)
    rounded = ((total_two / total * 100) - 100)
    self.loss_gain_main.set("%.2f" % rounded + "%")
    self.top.destroy()

def cancel(self, event = None):
    self.top.destroy()

def delete_record(self):
    top = self.top = Toplevel()

    top.bind("<Return>", self.delete)

    Label(top, text = "Please enter code of record to be deleted: ").grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = E, padx = 5, pady = 5)

    self.code_entry_delete = StringVar()
    Entry(top, textvariable = self.code_entry_delete).grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.code_entry_delete.set("")

    Button(top, text = "Delete Record", command = self.delete).grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Button(top, text = "Cancel", command = self.cancel).grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)

def delete(self, event = None):
    if self.code_entry_delete.get() in self.code_list:
        self.label1.grid_forget()
        self.label2.grid_forget()
        self.label3.grid_forget()
        self.label4.grid_forget()
        self.label5.grid_forget()
        self.label6.grid_forget()
        self.label7.grid_forget()
        self.label8.grid_forget()
        self.label9.grid_forget()
        self.label10.grid_forget()
        self.top.destroy()

def company_details(self, event):
    self.priceVar.set("$" + (ystockquote.get_price(self.entryVar.get() + ".AX")))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("https://au.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" + (self.entryVar.get() + ".AX")).read(), "html.parser")
    element = soup.find("div", ("class", "title"))
    name = element.find("h2")
    self.companyVar.set(name.text[:-9])

def onFrameConfig(self, event):
    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    master = Tk()
    master.title("Share Program")
    app = Shares(master)
    master.geometry("1235x528+20+40")
    master.mainloop()
```

Comment: I would suggest creating lots of frames to keep the labels in so you can just delete the whole frame.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I can't really get my head around how that would work, but I don't think it's feasible since I've set my frame up inside a canvas with a scrollbar so that you can add as many rows as you want and the canvas will expand to cater for it. The way I see it, creating lots of frames will limit the entries to how many frames I create.

Comment: Yes but you can create as many frames as you want.

Comment: Could I ask how? Creating extra rows as needed is done by `self.rows += 1`. How do you apply this to frames? I'm very new to Python and programming so have much to learn.

Comment: To clarify - say I create 15 frames. What happens if I want 16 entries? Right now I just add a new record and the canvas with scrollbar allows this. If I create 15 frames and want 16 entries, I'm going to have to re-code my app and add more frames each time. Does that makes sense, or am I being fussy?

Comment: Yes it sort of makes sense… but you can create a function that creates more frames. I can't get the `ystockquote` and `urllib.request` modules so I can't help much but I will post a function that creates more frames so you can try to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thank you, that's much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that might help you. To create a new frame call `add_frame()` then to delete a frame call `framelist[whatevernumbertheframeis].destroy()`.
To create widgets in the frame go `Label(framelist[framenumber], text="etc.")` and to create a widget in the last created frame do `Label(framelist[-1], text="etc.")`. Hope this helps!

```
from Tkinter import *
framelist=[]
frames=1
def add_frame():
    global frames
    framelist.append(Frame(root))
    framelist[-1].grid()
    frames+=1

root=Tk()
for i in range(20):
    add_frame()
    Label(framelist[i], text="Frame %i" % (i)).grid()
framelist[6].destroy()
root.mainloop()
```

Now because I don't have your modules, I can't do it perfectly but here is an example of how you could do part of it.

P.S There are still multiple errors in the code...

```
from Tkinter import *
import ystockquote
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


"""

I am adding comments so that if
you need help from stackoverflow
on this again they will know whats
what because it took me a looooong time

"""




class Shares(Frame):
# Main page to display gain/loss on different shares
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.frame = Frame(master, bg = "#ededed")
        self.frame.grid(row = 9, column = 0)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame, bg = "#ffffff")
        self.data_frame = Frame(self.canvas, bg = "#ffffff")
        self.vscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.frame, orient = "vertical", command = self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = self.vscrollbar.set)
        self.vscrollbar.grid(row = 9, column = 11, sticky = NS)
        self.canvas.config(width = 1210, height = 200)
        self.canvas.grid(row = 9, column = 0, columnspan = 11, sticky = E)
        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window = self.data_frame, anchor = "nw", tags = "self.frame")
        self.data_frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfig)

        self.data_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize = 352)
        self.data_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1,  minsize = 96)
        self.data_frame.grid_columnconfigure(2,  minsize = 96)
        self.data_frame.grid_columnconfigure(3,  minsize = 96)
        self.data_frame.grid_columnconfigure(4,  minsize = 96)
        self.data_frame.grid_columnconfigure(5,  minsize = 96)
        self.data_frame.grid_columnconfigure(6,  minsize = 96)
        self.data_frame.grid_columnconfigure(7,  minsize = 96)
        self.data_frame.grid_columnconfigure(8,  minsize = 96)
        self.data_frame.grid_columnconfigure(9,  minsize = 96)

        master.bind("<Return>", self.company_details)

        Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", font = "Helvetica 20", text = "Enter ASX Code").grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", font = "Helvetica 20", text = "Current Price").grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady = 5)

        self.entryVar = StringVar()
        Entry(self.frame, width = 12, font = "Helvetica 20", textvariable = self.entryVar).grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)

        self.companyVar = StringVar()
        Label(self.frame, font = "Helvetica 20", textvariable = self.companyVar).grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady = 5)

        self.priceVar = DoubleVar()
        Label(self.frame, font = "Helvetica 20", textvariable = self.priceVar).grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.priceVar.set("")

        Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", font = "Helvetica 20", text = "Current Action").grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady = 5)

        Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", font = "Helvetica 20", text = "Current Holdings").grid(row = 7, column = 0, pady = 5)

        Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", width = 10, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "Name").grid(row = 8, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", width = 10, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "Code").grid(row = 8, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)
        Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", width = 10, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "Buy Date").grid(row = 8, column = 3, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", width = 10, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "Quantity").grid(row = 8, column = 4, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", width = 10, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "Paid").grid(row = 8, column = 5, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", width = 10, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "Brokerage").grid(row = 8, column = 6, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", width = 10, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "Total").grid(row = 8, column = 7, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", width = 10, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "Current").grid(row = 8, column = 8, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", width = 10, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "Total").grid(row = 8, column = 9,padx = 5, pady = 5)
        Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", width = 10, font = "Helvetica 14 bold", text = "Loss/Gain").grid(row = 8, column = 10, padx = 5, pady = 5)

        Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", text = "Amount").grid(row = 16, column = 10, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)
        Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", text = "Amount").grid(row = 16, column = 9, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)
        Label(self.frame, bg = "#ededed", text = "Amount").grid(row = 16, column = 8, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)

        Button(self.frame, width = 11, text = "New Record", command = self.new_record).grid(row = 16, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)
        #Button(self.frame, width = 11, text = "Modify Record", command = self.new_record).grid(row = 16, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        Button(self.frame, width = 11, text = "Delete Record", command = self.delete_record).grid(row = 16, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)

        self.rows = 0

        self.code_list = {}
# Function to validate Australian company codes
    def validate_code(self):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("https://au.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" + (self.code_entry.get() + ".AX")).read(), "html.parser")
        element = soup.find("div", ("class", "title"))
        name = element.find("h2")
        self.name_entry.set(name.text[:-9])
# Adding a new company
    def new_record(self):
        top = self.top = Toplevel()

        top.bind("<Return>", self.add)

        Label(top, text = "Code: ").grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = E, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        Label(top, text = "Name: ").grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = E, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        Label(top, text = "Buy Date: ").grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = E, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        Label(top, text = "Quantity: ").grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = E, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        Label(top, text = "Paid: ").grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = E, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        Label(top, text = "Brokerage: ").grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = E, padx = 5, pady = 5)

        self.name_main = StringVar()

        self.name_entry = StringVar()
        Entry(top, textvariable = self.name_entry).grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.name_entry.set("")

        self.code_main = StringVar()

        self.code_entry = StringVar()
        Entry(top, textvariable = self.code_entry, validatecommand = self.validate_code).grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.code_entry.set("")

        self.date_main = StringVar()


        self.date_entry = StringVar()
        Entry(top, textvariable = self.date_entry).grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.date_entry.set("")

        self.quantity_main = IntVar()


        self.quantity_entry = IntVar()
        Entry(top, textvariable = self.quantity_entry).grid(row = 4, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.quantity_entry.set("")

        self.paid_main = DoubleVar()


        self.paid_entry = DoubleVar()
        Entry(top, textvariable = self.paid_entry).grid(row = 5, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.paid_entry.set("")
        self.frames=[]
        self.column=0            

        self.brokerage_main = DoubleVar()

        self.brokerage_entry = DoubleVar()
        Entry(top, textvariable = self.brokerage_entry).grid(row = 6, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.brokerage_entry.set(29.95)
        # 
        self.total_main = DoubleVar()

        self.current_main = DoubleVar()

        self.total_two_main = DoubleVar()

        self.loss_gain_main = DoubleVar()

        self.frames.append(Frame(self.data_frame))
        self.frames[-1].grid()
        Label(self.frames[-1], textvariable=self.name_main).grid(row=self.rows, column=1)
        Label(self.frames[-1], textvariable=self.code_main).grid(row=self.rows, column=2)
        Label(self.frames[-1], textvariable=self.date_main).grid(row=self.rows, column=3)
        Label(self.frames[-1], textvariable=self.quantity_main).grid(row=self.rows, column=4)
        Label(self.frames[-1], textvariable=self.paid_main).grid(row=self.rows, column=1)
        Label(self.frames[-1], textvariable=self.brokerage_main).grid(row=self.rows, column=6)
        Label(self.frames[-1], textvariable=self.total_main).grid(row=self.rows, column=7)
        Label(self.frames[-1], textvariable=self.current_main).grid(row=self.rows, column=8)
        Label(self.frames[-1], textvariable=self.total_two_main).grid(row=self.rows, column=9)
        Label(self.frames[-1], textvariable=self.loss_gain_main).grid(row=self.rows, column=10)
        self.rows+=1


        Button(top, text = "Validate code", command = self.validate_code).grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)

        Button(top, text = "Add", command = self.add).grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady = 5)

        Button(top, text = "Cancel", command = self.cancel).grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = E, padx = 5, pady = 5)

    def add(self, event = None):
        self.rows += 1
        self.code_list[self.code_entry.get()]=self.frames[-1]
        code = str.upper(self.code_entry.get())
        self.code_main.set(code)
        self.name_main.set(self.name_entry.get())
        self.date_main.set(self.date_entry.get())
        self.quantity_main.set(self.quantity_entry.get())
        paid = self.paid_entry.get()
        self.paid_main.set("$%.2f" % paid)
        brokerage = self.brokerage_entry.get()
        self.brokerage_main.set("$%.2f" % brokerage)
        total = self.quantity_entry.get() * self.paid_entry.get() + self.brokerage_entry.get()
        self.total_main.set("$%.2f" % total)
        self.current_main.set("$" + str(ystockquote.get_price(self.code_entry.get() + ".AX")))
        curent_main = float(ystockquote.get_price(self.code_entry.get() + ".AX"))
        total_two = self.current_main * self.quantity_entry.get()
        self.total_two_main.set("$%.2f" % total_two)
        rounded = ((total_two / total * 100) - 100)
        self.loss_gain_main.set("%.2f" % rounded + "%")
        self.top.destroy()

    def cancel(self, event = None):
        self.top.destroy()

    def delete_record(self):
        top = self.top = Toplevel()

        top.bind("<Return>", self.delete)

        Label(top, text = "Please enter code of record to be deleted: ").grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = E, padx = 5, pady = 5)

        self.code_entry_delete = StringVar()
        Entry(top, textvariable = self.code_entry_delete).grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.code_entry_delete.set("")

        Button(top, text = "Delete Record", command = self.delete).grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        Button(top, text = "Cancel", command = self.cancel).grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)

    def delete(self, event = None):
        if self.code_entry_delete.get() in self.code_list:
            self.code_list[self.code_entry_delete.get()].destroy()


    def company_details(self, event):
        self.priceVar.set("$" + (ystockquote.get_price(self.entryVar.get() + ".AX")))

        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("https://au.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" + (self.entryVar.get() + ".AX")).read(), "html.parser")
        element = soup.find("div", ("class", "title"))
        name = element.find("h2")
        self.companyVar.set(name.text[:-9])

    def onFrameConfig(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    master = Tk()
    master.title("Share Program")
    app = Shares(master)
    master.geometry("1235x528+20+40")
    master.mainloop()
```

Comment: My brain is practically melting trying to adapt that to my program. I appreciate your help but I can't seem to figure out how it works into my app. I've changed my label to `self.label2 = Label(self.framelist[i], textvariable = self.code_main)` and added `self.add_frame()` but it's all a bit messy and convoluted atm… if you could provide any further guidance on how to implement your code I would be grateful.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm still trying to get my head around so many new programming concepts that it can be a little overwhelming at times. If there is another approach I could take to solve label removal, (or adding/removing records in general) which you think is worthwhile looking into, I'd be happy for any recommendation. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you. It worked!!! I honestly don't know what you did but the code worked. I'll try and study the code to work it all out. One thing I noticed which confused me was `[- 1]`. How does that work when you're adding a frame? Also, I noticed the column width formatting and `self.variable.set("")` is not being applied on the GUI. Is there any way of getting the frame to recognise data formatting, or is this a trade-off for being able to add new frames? I tried changing the frame object formatting rules from `self.data_frame` to `self.frames` but it didn't work. Anyway, I can't thank you enough!

Comment: Cheers! (it took me long enough so i'm glad it worked!). The `[-1]` bit is not subtract 1 it is the last item added to the list. The frame issue though is because each frame has their independent grid. It would be possible to align each label with the labels in `self.data_frame` but it would be a seperate question. Anyway, if you need more help you can contact me directly from my incomplete [website](http://pythonqanda.weebly.com)